# AJAX Javascript Strings and Pyamid

Tags: javascript, ajax, pyramid

I'm building a pyramid web app and I'm trying to implement the JavaScript markdown editor EpicEditor in order to edit markdown files.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "{{ request.resource_url(context) }}raw_markdown",
    context: document.body,
    success: function(md){
        markdown = md;
    }
})
var opts = { 
    basePath: '{{ request.static_url('plcars:static/') }}',
    focusOnLoad: true,
    clientSideStorage: false,
    autogrow: true,
    file: { defaultContent: markdown }
};
var editor = new EpicEditor(opts);
editor.load();
```

But EpicEditor then acts as if `markdown` is empty. If I call `alert(markdown)`, it's also empty, and if I try `document.write(markdown);` nothing happens either.

I know that the URL of the ajax call works, as I can see in my Firefox web console that the request succeeds. Also, if I type in the console to see the value of the variable markdown, it is just as it should be (e.g., `"This is my text"`).

Before this, I had tried to pass the markdown through a JSON container, and that seemed to go well except that the string could never be displayed on the page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should put your code inside `success` callback, since your `$.ajax` call is asynchronous:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "{{ request.resource_url(context) }}raw_markdown",
    context: document.body,
    success: function (md) {
        markdown = md;
        var opts = {
            basePath: '{{ request.static_url('plcars:static/') }}',
            focusOnLoad: true,
            clientSideStorage: false,
            autogrow: true,
            file: {
                defaultContent: markdown
            }
        };
        var editor = new EpicEditor(opts);
        editor.load();
    }
})
```